# Why can I not access global variables in my js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

I am trying to set up a set of global variables in my js app script that allows me to access them throughout my functions in the page and the site. For some reason I keep getting undefined in my console even though I know the objects are there.

This is my js snippet the js is quite long so I thought I would show you the important bit thats wrong(i think)

```
(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    var global = function() {
        this.init();
    };

    global.prototype = {

        // ------------------------------------
        // Global variables

            mainContainer : 'div#container',
            tmbContainer : '.rsThumbsContainer',
            tmbContainerT : '.rsThumbsContainer',
            slider : '.collection #gallery-t-group',
            body : 'body',
            close : '<div class="close-button" id="close"><p class="icon-close"></p></div>',
            socials : '.socialbar-vertical',
            loader : '<div class="loader"></div>',
            gallery : '.collection #gallery-t-group',


        // ------------------------------------
        // Initialise

        init: function() {

            var app = this;

            this.testGlobals();
            this.loadSlide();
            this.fakingIt();
            this.unloadSlide();
            this.mobileNav();
            this.loadThumbs();
            this.royalSlider();
            this.thumbsSwitch();
            this.functionResize();
            this.theSocialActivated();
            this.theSliderActivated();
            this.theSliderDeactivated();
            this.slideEventChange();

            console.log('======> new.global.js');


        },

        // ------------------------------------
        // Functions
        testGlobals: function () {
            console.log(body);
        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        new global();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

In my console I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined
```

Is there a simple thing I am missing here.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of prototypes. All those properties should probably be in the constructor, at least.

Comment: Your code doesn't create *any* global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
testGlobals: function () {
            console.log(body);
        }
```

with

```
testGlobals: function () {
            console.log(this.body);
        }
```

or

```
testGlobals: function () {
            console.log(global.body);
        }
```

Comment: this.body worked perfectly, I think I will need to declare some like `var s = this;` in the function and access it like that instead so for instance `s.myFunction();` or `s.find(element);`